# How to integrate agora sdk in codeigniter

Tags: agora.io

I'm trying using agora SDK([www.agora.io](http://www.agora.io)) to add 1:1 video call into my web application. I use codeigniter for my project. How to integrate agora SDK in codeigniter using libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Agora's Web SDK is a Javascript front-end/client-side SDK and Codeigniter is a PHP framework so there isn't any PHP library to import. You'll have to implement Agora using Javascript and have it interact with the html embedded in your Codeigniter views.